# An automatically gas payment

Tags: gas, payments

I’m a noob in smart contract development so I have a question. Is it possible to make that the smart contract itself can pay gas needed for executing? Or could I chose an address which should pay the transaction automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that has to send the transaction have to pay the transaction gas. I dont think contract can pay `transaction gas` but they can relay the gas they have been assigned to other `contracts`. You can check out [Meta transactions](https://medium.com/@austin_48503/ethereum-meta-transactions-90ccf0859e84)
Using this method we are able to interact with the blockchain from accounts that don’t hold any Ether